# Difference between two programs - Include file.h inlcuded or not in file.c

Tags: c, include, header-files

I wrote two simple and short programs, each composed by three file (main.c, libreria_mia.c, libreria_mia.h).
The first program works also if i don't write #include "libreria_mia.h" in the file libreria_mia.c.
Instead the second program works only i write the above include in libreria_mia.c

How come?

First program:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libreria_mia.h"

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = quadrato(x);
    printf("%d\n", y);
    return 0;
}

------------------------------------------
// libreria_mia.h
int quadrato(int a);

------------------------------------------
// libreria_mia.c
int quadrato(int a)
{
    a = a * a;
    return a;
}
```

Second program:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libreria_mia.h"

int x = 5;

int main()
{
    quadrato();
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
----------------------------------------------------------------
// libreria_mia.h
extern int x;
void quadrato();
----------------------------------------------------------------
// libreria_mia.c
#include "libreria_mia.h"

void quadrato()
{
       x = x * x;
}
```

Thank you for your willingness.

Comment: They differ because the second one needs the `extern` declaration at compile time. However the compiler's assumptions about the function are correct, and the linker finds it.

Comment: Hello @WeatherVane thank you so much for your comment. Is it better to include always the file.h in the file.c to avoid problems?

Comment: Yes, always include full references.